# c++ program for arduino failing

Tags: arduino, ubuntu-12.04, arduino-ide

I'm trying to write a simple / my first hello world program for the arduino using ther IDE.

I have the following code block:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Hello, world!");
  delay(1000);
}
```

When i compile, I get the following error message:

```
/home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++: line 3: /home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../bin.gcc/avr-g++: cannot execute binary file
/home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++: line 3: /home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../bin.gcc/avr-g++: Success
/home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ returned 126
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**

How I've connected the Arduino:

I've connected it via USB. I can see it via the menu option in the IDE... and it's checked off properly. I've also ensured that I've selected the correct board type - UNO. the board itself has power. The ON led is green. And when i upload the code, the TX led flashes.

**EDIT 2**

Following the advice found here:  http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=18183

I renamed the folder and it compiles.  But it doesn't let me upload the code to the board.   I get the error:

```
Binary sketch size: 1,672 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
/home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avrdude: 1: /home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avrdude: ELF: not found
/home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avrdude: 2: /home/jj/Documents/arduino-1.0.5/hardware/tools/avrdude: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: how did you compile it?

Comment: using the arduino IDE's compile button!  It's their "Verify" button...

Comment: is that all? I mean the entire program? Seems C# rather than C++ from just this snippet without any header..

Comment: that's it.  that's the entire program.

Comment: Your code looks okay, how is your arduino physically connected?

Comment: @Nathan connected via USB.  I can see it via the menu option in the IDE... and it's checked off properly.  I've also ensured that I've selected the correct board type - UNO.  the board itself has power.  The ON led is green.  And when i upload the code, the TX led flashes...

Comment: @Nathan could it be a permissions thing with linux?

Comment: Try giving this a go. I doubt it's permissions related, you'd probably get an error earlier in that case. `http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=18183`

Comment: hey... that kinda worked.  it lets me compile but not upload the code.

Comment: @DavidKernin: The Arduino libraries supply `main()`, and the tools add in most of the required headers before compilation. Arduino "sketches" are basically just C++ snippets included into a larger chunk of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely uninstalled the Arduino IDE and all dependencies. 
Then i used the software center in ubuntu to find and install the IDE. 
and now its working.